# How to solve ajaxcontroltoolkit.extendercontrolbase.dispose() error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an application in which ajaxcntroltoolkit is used.This control is added on a usercontrol whose top code is

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
```

This user control is added on an aspx page and this page is inherited from a master page.
When control goes to master page error is shown as

Locating source for 'f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {ee 1a 1d c3 d5 ca a 7d 84 6b 74 7f 51 e8 63 6b}

[image]

How to solve this error i have tried using latest version of ajaxcontroltoolkit but same error exists.

Comment: People won't be able to read that image very well, you should produce the exact error and information in the content of the post itself, in text.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the reference properties of the AjaxControlTollkit has Copy Local set to True. I think you don't have that Assembly in the Bin folder on the server.